# Odd convex function is constant proof

Tags: convex-analysis

I need help solving this: if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an odd convex function, then  $f=ax $ for any a∈R

Comment: Wouldn't it be concave as well?

Comment: Note that $f(0)=0$ by the *odd* condition. Then think at a convex function that intersects a line at $\gt 2$ points, and why it can't be *strictly* convex. P.S. $f(x)=x$ is an odd convex non-constant function, so your question must be misstating something.

Comment: So should the question be to prove thats its linear?

Comment: Ok I've  proven that if f is both convex and concave then this  equality  holds  f(ax1+(a-1)x2)=af(x1)+(a-1)f(x2) ... but how can i prove that f=ax

Answer (score 2):

The question is incorrect as pointed out by dxiv. $f(x)=x$ is a counter example.

I am addressing the question of what is an odd convex function.

Since $f$ is an odd function,

$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$

If $f(x)$ is convex, then $-f(x)$ is concave.

Hence $f(-x)$ is concave which imply that $f(x)$ is a concave function.

In summary $f(x)$ is both convex and concave. Can you conclude what type of function is both convex and concave?

Comment: All such functions  are  $f(x)=ax$  where $a \in R.$  No more!